# Reload template after error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I am in `tickets/new` and create a new ticket with errors, my URL gets reconstructed to `tickets/`.  How can I stay on the same page and reload the page with errors instead of redirecting?

In my ticket controller:

```
if @ticket.valid?
  @ticket.save
  redirect_to tickets_path
else
  render :template => 'tickets/new'
end
```

**UPDATE**

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users
root :to => 'tickets#index'
resources :users do
  resources :tickets
end
resources :tickets
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
render :template => 'tickets/new'
```

try this:

```
render 'new'
```

Comment: Still taking me to `tickets/`

Comment: Your ticket controller code, is that in the create method in the tickets_controller?

Comment: Yeah, it is.  In my new method, I have this code:   def new
    if user_signed_in?
      @ticket = Ticket.new
    else
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end

Comment: do you have any validations in your Ticket model? it seems like the ticket is saving and redirecting to index.

Comment: Yeah, I have validations in my model and they're not being saved :/

Comment: noticed that you have `resources: tickets` listed twice in your routes, maybe that is causing an issue?

Comment: Nice catch, but that didn't fix the issue. Been wrapping my head around this for a long time but still not quite sure where to look.